# Getting "Activity not found exception" while using "market://details?id=my_package_name"

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I am using this method on a button click.
My app is not yet launched in google play so I tried using some other app's package name in the URI. I tried many different packages but always I am getting "Activity not found exception"

```
public void rateApp(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=mobi.infolife.installer"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", "Exception is "+e);
        }
    }
```

can anyone say what wrong is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing this is on the emulator. "market://" links only works when Google Play app is installed on the device.

If it's not installed (you have exception) then you can launch the web browser.

Comment: Thanks @Ran. You were right. I tried in device and it worked fine.

Comment: +1Ran @PradeepCR : you can accept his answer if u get solution